# Looping Through R data to replace all values

Tags: r, for-loop

Basic level R programmer trying to re-calibrate data using a weighted effect and some other value.  In particular I want to 1) if the weighted effect is negative take the row value of X and subtract the person's value or 2) if the weighted effect is positive take the person's value and subtract X.

Mock data:

```
p1 <- c(0.4,0.7,0.3,0.2)
p2 <- c(0.8,0.4,0.5,0.1)
p3 <- c(0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3)
wef <- c(1.5,-1.2,1.8,-1.3)
x <- c(0.5,0.4,0.6,0.2)

print(df)
   p1  p2  p3  wef   x
1 0.4 0.8 0.6  1.5 0.5
2 0.7 0.4 0.5 -1.2 0.4
3 0.3 0.5 0.4  1.8 0.6
4 0.2 0.1 0.3 -1.3 0.2
```

I attempted this (which did nothing and likely would be inefficient with for loops):

```
for(row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for(col in 1:ncol(df)) {
    ifelse(weightef[row] < 0, df[row,col]==(df$x[row]-df[row,col]),
           df[row,col]==df[row,col]-df$x[row])
  }
}
```

my desired output in case the above was to hard to follow is this

```
 person1 person2 person3 weightef x
1    -0.1     0.3     0.1      1.5   0.5
2    -0.3     0.0    -0.1     -1.2   0.4
3    -0.3    -0.1    -0.2      1.8   0.6
4     0.0     0.1    -0.1     -1.3   0.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using `apply` and `ifelse` function in R. This is just one line function, and you are not required to understand `grep`. The second line of code just put everything into data frame.

```
result <- apply(df[, 1:3], 2, FUN = function(y) with(df, ifelse(wef < 0, x - y, y - x)))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(result, wef, x))

    p1   p2   p3  wef   x
1 -0.1  0.3  0.1  1.5 0.5
2 -0.3  0.0 -0.1 -1.2 0.4
3 -0.3 -0.1 -0.2  1.8 0.6
4  0.0  0.1 -0.1 -1.3 0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this without a loop in `R`

```
nm1 <- grep("^p\\d+", names(df), value = TRUE)
i1 <- df$wef > 0 
df[i1, nm1] <- df[i1, nm1]  - df$x[i1]
df[!i1, nm1] <- df$x - df[!i1, nm1]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(p1, p2, p3, wef, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use for loops you can do it in this way

```
#Create dataframe
df = data.frame(p1, p2, p3, wef, x)

#looping lenght of vector wef
for (w in 1:length(df$wef))
{
  #Checking positive or negative weight
  if (df$wef[w] >= 0)
  {
    #subtracting
    df$p1[w] = df$p1[w] - df$x[w]
    df$p2[w] =  df$p2[w] - df$x[w]
    df$p3[w] =  df$p3[w] - df$x[w]
  }
  else
  {
    #subtracting
    df$p1[w] = df$x[w] - df$p1[w]
    df$p2[w] = df$x[w] -  df$p2[w]
    df$p3[w] = df$x[w] -  df$p3[w]
  }
}

#print result
print(df)
    p1   p2   p3  wef   x
1 -0.1  0.3  0.1  1.5 0.5
2 -0.3  0.0 -0.1 -1.2 0.4
3 -0.3 -0.1 -0.2  1.8 0.6
4  0.0  0.1 -0.1 -1.3 0.2
```